# Should it step 2 registration / onboarding be a method or a new controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm working on an app. Registration of user is through omniauth, and using Twitter.

What I'd like to do is after that registration is complete, ask that you add your email.

Should I create a new controller called say setups, or should I create a method called setup under the users_controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically either is fine, I would however just drop them on their `show` action and prompt them there to enter their email address.